# how to cancel a vibration in alert box?

Tags: android, popup, android-alertdialog, vibration

I'm creating a app that popup a alert box that have to vibrate until the user click ok or cancel
my app vibrate good when i open the alert box but when i click ok or cancel app crash

this is coding i used for creating a alert box with vibrate

```
Vibrator v;
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAlert);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            vibration();
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                            v.cancel();

                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                            v.cancel();
                        }
                    });


                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();


                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            });
```

and this is a vibrate method

```
public  void vibration()
    {

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        long[] pattern = { 0, 3000, 3000 };


        v.vibrate(pattern, 0);
//      v.vibrate(5000);

    }
```

I am getting error when i used Vibrator.cancel(); or v.cancel(); can any one help me

Comment: Try to cancel vibrate before finish Activity...

Comment: i try that also till i am getting same error msg "09-13 12:20:42.872: E/AndroidRuntime(3064): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception" this is msg i'm geting

Comment: try to surround it in a try and catch block!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vibrate(3000);` which is equivalent to let the device vibrate for 3 seconds, insted of trying to cancel a started service.

Comment: No i cant do that bcz my app is to vibrate till the user respond to that msg

Answer (score 0):

set the alert flag from default to

```
notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

This way, the notification will not cause vibrate.

If you want to make it vibrate also, you will have to give permission in manifest file for it
Make sure that application seeks vibrate permission in manifest. The application crash is due to the reason that your application does not have permission to vibrate the phone.

Here is the code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Edit:

I think you what you need is something different. You need a way to stop vibration after starting it.

Vibration service runs in a different context and hence you might not be able to communicate with it directly. There are several ways to do that but I am suggesting another easy way.

Instead of running vibration continuously, try running it for a small interval and put a timer in your dialog that will fire the vibration on after some time.

This way, you will not have to stop the vibration. As soon as the dialog is dismissed, the timer will stop firing and vibrate will stop. You will not need to explicitly turn off the vibration.

Comment: where should i put this coding in my app. instead off v.cancel? ya

Comment: @Jagan the above permission will go to your android menifest file

Comment: i am asking abt notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

Comment: can u give some example for this plz

Answer (score 0):

Try to cancel the vibrator before exiting from the Dialog. See [Vibrator class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html)  for more details.

Comment: http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/vibration-examples-for-android-phone-development/ you can check this link

Comment: from this example only i did vibrate but it is not working when i combine with alert box

Answer (score 0):

try like below.....

```
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    long[] pattern = {0,1000,1000};

    v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

Comment: if i put this code it will vibrate till the user click cancel or ok

Comment: vibrate without pattern for vibrate like notification.....try with v.vibrate( 1000 );... for vibrate sometimes & stops....

Comment: i don't want vibrate to stop until the user respond to the msg

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have `v.cancel();` but as i can see this variable is not initialized, you are using another variable inside the function `vibration()` try to cancel an initialized variable of vibrate .
use this function

```
public Vibrator vibration() {

    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    long[] pattern = { 0, 3000, 3000 };

    v.vibrate(pattern, 0);
    // v.vibrate(5000);
    return v;

}
```

and start the vibration like that

```
final Vibrator v = vibration();
```

P.S. i know it is an old question but maybe someone want the answer.